# Muslim couple provocatively pictured on beach — true holiday photo or fake (i.e. staged/set up)?

Tags: religion, islam, gender, photography, muslims

Recently I found a very provocative picture circulating in anti-Islam communities. It shows a presumably Muslim man, who is wearing a very small bathing suit and is standing next to a fully clothed woman in black jilbab.

### The question

The primary question is: **Is the photo below a true holiday photo as one would initially think, or is it fake (staged, set up, edited, photoshopped, etc.)?** I'm skeptical about it being real because there are a number of Islamic traditions and doctrines that make it highly unusual these two would be pictured like this.

If possible, I would also be interested in the following:

- Who took the picture?
- Where was this picture taken?
- When was this picture taken?

[image]

Here's one example of it being used in anti-Islam circles, with 7.5K retweets and almost 33K likes at the moment of writing: https://twitter.com/Imamofpeace/status/1291340727490764801
[image]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111565/discussion-between-oddthinking-and-fattie).

Comment: I don't know about this specific picture, but I was at the beach a few days ago and saw families dressed like this (in the Netherlands). It doesn't seem that strange.

Comment: Is this something skeptical about? A picture of of two human beings on beach??

Comment: @PAS As a person with close to zero local muslims around me, I really have no clue what they might do or wear at the beach, so being skeptically minded, yes, I might easily believe this is completely fake. Or rather, for the sake of enlightenment, knowing really what a day at the beach looks like for a muslim family is an interesting thought, but that would probably be harder to work into a question that accords with site guidelines.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A Google image search suggests it comes from [Villa Next Door: Graduation Show 2017; Royal Academy of Art, The Hague](https://villanextdoor.wordpress.com/2017/07/04/graduation-show-2017-royal-academy-of-art-the-hague/) and is part of the portfolio created by an artist, Jaimy Gail.

Since it is described as a graduation show for an academy, it was presumably produced as part of a course at the academy.

Due to the attention the picture has been getting, the editor of the show has appended this message to the photograph.

> FOR ALL THOSE WATCHING AT THE MOMENT: THIS IS NOT AN ANTI-ISLAM OR PRO-ISLAM IMAGE. THIS IS A STAGED WORK OF ART. WHICH MEANS THERE IS MORE IN IT THAN JUST PRO OR ANTI SOMETHING. AND ONLY AS SUCH IT HAS TO DO WITH REALITY.

Comment: it's unfortunate that this question was closed. here is some more evidence that the photographer stages her photos https://www.wulmagazine.com/photography/jaimy-gail

Comment: @Avery An NSFW warning would have been in its place.